# Find stream path for resource in xamarin

Tags: android, xml, path, xamarin, resources

I am using `xamarin` for android and I tried to find path for an `XML` file to read/edit/write it.

At First, I tried in assets but I cant write from it, so I'm trying to find a path for the `Resources` directory .

I know that the path for assets is

```
StreamReader rInereral=new  StreamReader("//data//data//MbProject.MbProject//files//invitation.xml");
```

and I tried to write a path:

```
StreamReader rInereral=new  StreamReader("//data//data//MbProject.MbProject//Resource//files//invitation.xml");
```

But it didn't work. 
Please help as fast as you can.

Comment: Both Assets and Resources are in the signed app bundle, which cannot be written to.

Comment: so how can i make a XML file that can read/edit/write ?